# Pandas pivot table selecting rows with maximum values

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have pandas dataframe as:

```
df

Id      Name        CaseId       Value 
82      A1          case1.01     37.71 
1558    A3          case1.01     27.71 
82      A1          case1.06     29.54 
1558    A3          case1.06     29.54 
82      A1          case1.11     12.09 
1558    A3          case1.11     32.09 
82      A1          case1.16     33.35 
1558    A3          case1.16     33.35
```

For each Id, Name pair I need to select the CaseId with maximum value.

i.e. I am seeking the following output:

```
Id      Name        CaseId       Value 
82      A1          case1.01     37.71
1558    A3          case1.16     33.35
```

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Id', 'Name'], columns=['CaseId'], values=['Value'], aggfunc=[np.max])['amax']
```

But all it does is for each `CaseId` as column it gives maximum value and not the results that I am seeking above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('Value').drop_duplicates(['Id'],keep='last')
Out[93]: 
     Id Name    CaseId  Value
7  1558   A3  case1.16  33.35
0    82   A1  case1.01  37.71
```

Since we post same time , adding more method

```
df.sort_values('Value').groupby('Id').tail(1)
Out[98]: 
     Id Name    CaseId  Value
7  1558   A3  case1.16  33.35
0    82   A1  case1.01  37.71
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
df = df.sort_values('Value', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Id').sort_index()
```

Output:

```
     Id Name    CaseId  Value
0    82   A1  case1.01  37.71
7  1558   A3  case1.16  33.35
```

Answer (score 2):

With `nlargest` and `groupby`

```
pd.concat(d.nlargest(1, ['Value']) for _, d in df.groupby('Name'))

     Id Name    CaseId  Value
0    82   A1  case1.01  37.71
7  1558   A3  case1.16  33.35
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to create a joint column, take its max, then split it back to two columns:

```
df['ValueCase'] = list(zip(df['Value'], df['CaseId']))
p = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Id', 'Name'], values=['ValueCase'], aggfunc='max')
p['Value'], p['CaseId'] = list(zip(*p['ValueCase']))
del p['ValueCase']
```

Results in:

```
             CaseId  Value
Id   Name                 
82   A1    case1.01  37.71
1558 A3    case1.16  33.35
```